Water filter connection to sink leaking even with tape
I bought an inline water filter to install in my apartment. I've installed similar units before and this one seemed even easier - you don't even need to mount it to the wall of the cabinet. I can't get the water connection to work, though. The pipe from the wall > unit works fine, but the connection from filter unit hose > sink hose leaks a lot, even after applying the plumber's tape. The female connector is much shorter than the male connector from the filter, but it screws in normally and is as tight as I can get it. What's going wrong?


Those fittings seal by compression with a rubber seal or washer in the female end. There should be no need for tape on the threads.  the tape may actually be causing the leak my preventing the 2 fittings from being tightened enough to seal.  take it apart and look in the female end for a black rubbed seal.

Those fittings seal by compression with a rubber seal or washer in the female end. There should be no need for tape on the threads.
The tape may actually be causing the leak my preventing the 2 fittings from being tightened enough to seal. take it apart and look in the female end for a black rubber seal.  If there is no seal you need a new hose.

There is a black seal in the female end that looks a bit dirty/damaged - am I able to replace it without replacing the hose? It does leak without tape.

I know of no replacement parts for that type of hose. you will need to replace the hose.
